# Creating a JavaScript Interface for Easing Function Configuration

Tags: javascript, interpolation, bezier, paperjs, easing-functions

I'm attempting to build a JavaScript interface to configure an easing function, similar to what's commonly seen in software like After Effects or Blender.

[image]

While I've made some progress, I'm not entirely satisfied with the results. I've experimented with various calculations, drawing inspiration from Bezier curves, but haven't achieved the desired outcome. I've set up a [StackBlitz environment](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mx5rgq?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FInterpolationPanel.vue,src%2FApp.vue,package.json&terminal=dev) to showcase my current implementation .

As you can observe, the control handles' influence is not up to par; although I've occasionally achieved better results for one or the other, there's always an issue.

This is the best result I'm able to achieve. The handle in the upper-right corner behaves as I'd like, but the handleA in the bottom-left corner appears to respond only to its Y position; its X axis has no effect:

```
const interpCurve = (t) => {
  const A = [0, 1];
  const B = [handlePosA.value.x, handlePosA.value.y];
  const C = [handlePosB.value.x, handlePosB.value.y];
  const D = [1, 0];

  const AB = interpolateLine(A, B, t);
  const BC = interpolateLine(B, C, t);
  const CD = interpolateLine(C, D, t);

  const ABBC = interpolateLine(AB, BC, t);
  const BCCD = interpolateLine(BC, CD, t);
  const ABBCBCCD = interpolateLine(ABBC, BCCD, t);

  const result = ABBCBCCD[1];
  return result;
};
```

Comment: what is your concrete question?

Comment: There is a standard way to apply this type of interface. It's difficult to describe because if it were clear in my mind, I don't think I would need to ask this question. I would like to find this procedure again, and I hope someone here who is more experienced than I am will be able to assist me.

Comment: We are typically dealing with an ease-in-out type of interface where two handles are accessible to control the curve. This kind of behavior can be found in many software applications

Comment: This is pretty much what SVG is for. A path with a single `C`, and two circles with touch/mouse handling JS. No need for any interpolation. It does the drawing for you.

Comment: No, SVGs are not my use case. I want to be able to retrieve the calculated values for this curve.

Comment: I could achieve it with SVGs, we agree, or even with Three.js or pure CSS, but that's not the aim of my question.

Comment: ... you know SVG is just another HTML element, right? You use an event listener for the SVG "circle" handles, then you update the SVG accordingly and get the resultant curve basically for free. That said, whether you do this with SVG or not, show a ([mcve]) runnable snippet in your post (and no need for the example images from other applications, web devs know what a curve control looks like =)

Comment: and how I get the precises values for each `t` I want? I mean, I want `y` value when `x` is 0.23, how do I do with SVG ? I don't think it will works

Comment: [like this, using JS](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#yforx), which doesn't really involve interpolation of any sort, but it does involve a bit of math because it's going to have to, since you're working with a non-linear curve mapping. (because weird as it may seem, this is actually - mathematically speaking - not a trivial problem. By fixing the start and end point, and restricting the control domain, we made it easier, but we only made it "easier", not "easy").

Comment: @snoobdogg why does result only return the y value? Assuming I understand the code properly.

Comment: @jordan, I tried to use a norm like  `Math.sqrt(ABBCBCCD[0]*ABBCBCCD[0]+ABBCBCCD[1]*ABBCBCCD[1])`  but then I've got a bell curve : (

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Why did you remove my reproduction on StackBlitz? I made the effort to provide one, and it's not enough? Now, I have to spend three hours learning how to do the same thing on Stack Overflow. Thank you for your help, but please move on to the next question and let me rollback my question.

Comment: Ah, probably caught in the deleting of the app screenshots (it was a number-linked link instead of a normal inline link). Let me put that back. (edit: nvm, looks like you restored it yourself).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ha, ok sorry then

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#yforx is exaclty what I'm looking for

Comment: Good to hear. Just note that there's a whole bunch of posts [on SO for finding Y for X in a bezier curve](https://www.google.com/search?q=y+for+x+bezier+stackoverflow+site:stackoverflow.com) though, so that definitely makes this a duplicate =D

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry for getting frustrated, but Stack Overflow is full of jerks, and that's actually how we learn on Stack Overflow - by encountering jerks empirically. So, we gradually build trigger warnings that make us unsure if we'll end up dealing with a jerk whenever we ask a new question and aren't sure if we've phrased it correctly. When you edited my question to remove my StackBlitz, I was 100% sure I had encountered another jerk.

Comment: @snoobdogg The issue is that the Bezier curve is sharing both it's x value and t value, which will not produce a true Bezier curve. I made changes to two functions to make it behave properly

drawInterpCurve:

    `...
    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        const normT = i / 200;
        const interpVal = interpCurve(normT);
        const x = interpVal[0] * 200;
        const y = 200 - (1 - interpVal[1]) * 200;
        curve.lineTo([x, y]);
    }
    ...`
 
interpCurve:

    `...
    
    return ABBCBCCD;`

Comment: @snoobdogg can't argue with that.

Comment: @Jordan it works like a charm ^^